# PHP and jquery function

Tags: php, jquery

I would like to know if this code is correct or not...

```
<?php foreach($ids as $id) { ?> 
  <script>
    loadMetadata(<?$id?>);
  </script> 
<?php }?>
```

or

```
<script>
  <?php foreach($ids as $id) ; ?> 
    loadMetadata(<?$id?>);
  <?php } ?>
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Same effect. First one generates more HTML. Both bad ways of doing things. Use AJAX.

Comment: `<?$id?>` doesnt makes any sense since variable itself return nothing you should use either `echo` or `<?= $id; ?>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) there. Your code will end up like this:

```
<script>
loadMetadata();
</script>
```

Add an `echo` before the `$id`. Also, not entirely sure if blocks work like that. I'd do it like this:

```
<?php foreach($ids as $id):?>
<script>
loadMetadata(<?php echo $id;?>)
</script>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

You can read more about this here: [Alternative syntax for control structures ¶](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)